# Edge cutting in Trees

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

A tree can be split into two different trees by removing one of its edges. Given a tree with `N` nodes uniquely identified by integer numbers in the `[0, N-1]` range, I need to write a function that finds the edge that needs to be removed from the tree, such that the difference between the sums of all the node IDs in the resulting trees is minimized.

The function should print the minimum difference that it found to the standard output (stdout).

The function will receive the following arguments:

`parent` which is an array of integer numbers with the following meaning: `parent[i]` = the parent of node `i` (more specifically its ID)

`parent[i] = -1` if i has no parent (i is the root of the tree)

**Data constraints**

The maximum number of nodes in the tree is 50,000

**Efficiency constraints**

The function is expected to print the result in less than 2 seconds

**Example**

```
 Input parent: [1, 4, 4, 2, -1, 2, 2]

 aka :         4
              / \
             1   2
            /  / | \
           0  3  5  6   

 Output: 9
```

Explanation: We remove the edge between nodes 2 and 6.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where you are stuck? Do you have any code that you have started with?

Answer (score 2):

1. For each node, compute the sum of its children, then add this value to itself, and store it in the node. Let's call this value `S_n` where `n` is a node. (Can be done easily by recursion & post-order traversal)
2. Find the node `n` which `S_n` has minimum difference to to `S_root/2`. The edge between n and its parent is the edge we want. (This requires linear time in worst case.)